# How to return rows with a specific value last?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My question is reverse of this question, [is it possible to define the sort order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789241/tsql-is-it-possible-to-define-the-sort-order).

I want to return some records from SQL Server database, sorted in ascending order based on a column's value BUT two particular records should always be on the end.

The original SQL (which needs to be changed) is below:

```
select code_id as CategoryID, code_desc as CategoryDescription
from codes
where code_id > '000001' and code_id < '000100'
order by CategoryDescription
```

The results are returned as

- 000003   ***First Record
- 000002   ***Another Record
- 000004   Apple
- 000016   Books
- 000014   Cables

I want the below result (first two with asteriks on the last):

- 000004   Apple
- 000016   Books
- 000014   Cables
- 000003   ***First Record
- 000002   ***Another Record

I tried the below UNION statement but the resultset is automatically sorted in ascending order and those two rows are in the beginning by default.

```
select code_id as CategoryID, code_desc as CategoryDescription
from codes
where code_id > '000003' and code_id < '000100' 
--order by categoryDescription

UNION

select code_id as CategoryID, code_desc as CategoryDescription
from codes
where code_id > '000001' and code_id < '000004'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems like a much simpler solution than introducing a bunch of unions:

```
SELECT code_id as CategoryID, code_desc as CategoryDescription
FROM dbo.codes
WHERE code_id > '000001' AND code_id < '000100'
ORDER BY CASE code_id
  WHEN '000002' THEN 3
  WHEN '000003' THEN 2 
  ELSE 1 END, CategoryDescription;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Select CategoryID, CategoryDescription from
(
select 1 as SortOrder, code_id as CategoryID, code_desc as CategoryDescription
from codes
where code_id > '000003' and code_id < '000100' 
--order by categoryDescription

UNION ALL

select 2 as SortOrder, code_id as CategoryID, code_desc as CategoryDescription
from codes
where code_id = '000003'

UNION ALL

select 3 as SortOrder, code_id as CategoryID, code_desc as CategoryDescription
from codes
where code_id = '000002'
) a
order by SortOrder  --and whatever else
```

Comment: The `ORDER BY SortOrder, CategoryDescription` will provide the order of the first query as well as the overall ordering desired.